# jQuery .each if/else statement

Tags: jquery, loops, if-statement, each

I have a jQuery statement that I want to loop through all divs with class "test_section_holder" and apply the if/else statement to the nearest "sub_ttl" div

Here is my jQuery - where would I place the .each

```
$(function() {
    // This will fire when document is ready:
   $('.sub_ttl').click(function ()  {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() >= 980) {
            // if larger or equal
            if( $('#test').hasClass('desktop_refine') && $(".test_section_holder").is(":visible"))
                {
                    $(".test_section_holder").closest(".test_section").find(".sub_ttl").toggleClass("mobileopen").removeClass("on");
                }
            } else {
                // if smaller
                $('#test').addClass('mobile_refine').removeClass('desktop_refine');
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="test_section">
        <span class="sub_ttl">Sub title 1</span>
        <div class="test_section_holder">
            Section 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_section">
        <span class="sub_ttl">Sub title 2</span>
        <div class="test_section_holder">
            Section 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
<style>
#test {height:auto; width:100%; overflow:hidden; font-family:arial; text-indent:15px;}
#test .test_section {height:auto; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
#test .test_section .sub_ttl {height:auto; width:100%; background:#000000; color:#ffffff; display:block; padding:15px 0;}
#test .test_section .test_section_holder {display:none; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:10px;}
#test .test_section .sub_ttl.on {background:yellow; color:#000000;}

#test .test_section .sub_ttl.mobileopen {background:red;}
#test .test_section .sub_ttl.mobileclosed {background:green;}
#test .test_section .sub_ttl.desktopopen {background:blue;}
#test .test_section .sub_ttl.desktopclosed {background:pink;}

@media only screen and (min-width:980px){
#test {width:300px;}    
#test .test_section .test_section_holder {display:block;}
}
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem?  What is happening vs. what you desire to happen?

Comment: I want to add a class to the sub_ttl div based on the condition of the if/else statement - if will need to be applied to each sub_ttl div individually based on the relevant test_section_holder div

Comment: So you want to replace the click method with a loop, or loop inside the click?

Comment: A loop inside the click... if possible

Comment: Definitely possible. You seem to have a fine grasp on jQuery. What's stopping you?

Comment: I can't work out where to get the .each - I've played around with it but can't get it to work. It currently looks at the first "test_section_holder" div and applies the logic for this to the second "test_section_holder" rather than seeing if the second "test_section_holder" is visible or not

Comment: Why will the click handler fire each time the window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
if ($('#test').hasClass('desktop_refine') {
    $(".test_section_holder").is(":visible").each(function () {
        $(this).closest(".test_section").find(".sub_ttl")
          .toggleClass("mobileopen") 
          .removeClass("on");
    });
} else {
    // if smaller
    $('#test').addClass('mobile_refine').removeClass('desktop_refine');
}
```

Comment: `.is()` returns `true` or `false`, not a collection. Use `.filter()` instead of `.is()`, or change the selector to `.test_section_holder:visible`